# images on Forestry.io upload in bad quality

Tags: html, image, crm

I'm using the CRM on **Forestry.oi** but some images get uploaded in a low quality. But before uploading them the quality is better. Is there any configuration to be made so the images don't lose the quality when displaying in the application?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's not a code problem, I don't get any error at my code, it's just that when I upload an image at server it has good quality. But when i upload it in my website it has bad quality